# What should print_r with a PDO statement in PHP return?

Tags: php

```
$dbh = new PDO ("sqlite:/Library/WebServer/Documents/nwind2009.db3");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers";     
print_r($dbh->query($sql));
```

This returns:

PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM Customers )

but if I do:

```
 foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo $row['CompanyName'];
 }
```

I get the data.

Why doesn't print_r show the database results?  What special thing is happening in the foreach?  I thought print_r showed me the array and that that was what I was doing in my foreach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you iterate over the query, it will automatically fetch the data. This is a good thing, because the adapter will lazy load the data the moment it is actually needed.

If you want to force the PDO adapter to fetch the data in advance, you can run the `fetchAll` method like so:

```
$dbh = new PDO ("sqlite:/Library/WebServer/Documents/nwind2009.db3");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers";       
print_r($dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll());
```

Answer (score 3):

A `PDOStatement` is an iterable interface to a resource stored outside your 'normal' PHP code. The resultset is not is not implemented at PHP level, and depending on the settings, it is even a question whether that resultset exists in the memory of the PHP process or in the memory of the database server. A `foreach` over it will actually call multiple fetches on the resource, and the fact you don't know (or should care) where that resultset is in memory is a Good Thing.

If you still need a representation for debugging, you can call a `var_dump($stmt->fetchALL());`

Answer (score 0):

The query returns an array/object and `print_r()` displays the results, adding the `<pre>` tags and passing true to `print_r()` will make it easier to read when displaying this on a HTML page

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(),true)."</pre><br />";
```